# yii2 viaTable, position property in middle table

Tags: yii2, relation

I have two ActiveRecord classes Question and Answer, in db they have many-to-many relation, so I have three tables.

question
| *question_id* | *name* |
| 1 | Test question |

answer
| *answer_id* | *name* |
| 1 | First |
| 1 | Second |

question_answers
| *question_id* | *answer_id* | *position* |
| 1             | 1           | 0          |
| 1             | 2           | 1          |

To link this active record in Question class I use that method:

```
public function getAnswers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::className(), ['answer_id' => 'answer_id'])
                ->viaTable('question_answers', ['question_id' => 'question_id']);
}
```

The question is how to add "position" property from db for all Answer in Question?
viaTable returns ActiveQuery but as I understand you can't add "position" here.
How to do it by Yii2? Is there some native solutions for such problems? Or if no is there some workaround for this?

P.S. As I understand this functionality execute 3 queries for each table, it was made for some caching solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position` column for questions, answers position will be stored in many-to-many table.

Possible workaround with relations:

`Question` model:

```
public function getQuestionToAnswers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(QuestionToAnswer::className(), ['question_id' => 'question_id'])
        ->orderBy([QuestionToAnswer::tableName() . 'position' => SORT_ASC]);
}
```

Separate model `QuestionToAnswer` for many-to-many table:

```
public function getAnswer()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Answer::className(), ['answer_id' => 'answer_id']);
}
```

And then you can pull the whole sorted list of questions with the sorted list of answers inside of each question.

```
$questions = Question::find()
    ->with('questionToAnswers.answer')
    ->orderBy([Question::tableName() . 'position' => SORT_ASC])
    ->all();

foreach ($questions as $question) {
    foreach ($question->questionToAnswers as $questionToAnswer) {
        echo $questionToAnswer->position; // Access position from many-to-many model attributes
        echo $questionToAnswer->answer->name; // Access answers attributes
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, One question has Many answers. Unless Anwers can belong to many questions, which would be weird.

Comment: Those question are not the same like on stackOverflow, I simplify table structures above. Questions may have answers that can be reused in others questions. Nevermind, main problem is "How to add property from middle table". But as I understand it can't be solve by native Yii mechanisms so the asnwer is correct.

Comment: You should definitely mention that in the question (that answers can belong to many questions).

Comment: Updated answer with possible workaround based on relations without manually constructing the query.